# How to select an item from <select> tag and save it as Foreign Key in ASP .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I have these two classes:
`State` and `Station` :

```
 public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Station> Stations { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Station
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}
```

The design was "Code First" and I used migration to set up the database and it was like:

[The station table saves StateId as foreign Key as it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HClwU.png)

My `StationsController.cs` file has a `Create` Method in which I use `ViewBag` for listing the state names like this:

```
// GET: Stations/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.StatesList = _context.States.ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

And finally my `HttpPost` `Create` method

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Code,Name,State")] Station station)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(station);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(station);
    }
```

My `create.cshtml` file has `<select>` tag like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="State" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="State" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.StatesList, "Id", "Name","State"))" ></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

The Issue I am facing is that after clicking `submit`, my `ModelState.isValid` remains `false` and the `State` field is `null` as shown in this image:

[The State Field is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7x2d.png)

The `Controller` has been autogenerated and only two things I have changed: 1st is that I have added the `ViewBag.StateList` in the `Create()` method and second is that I have added a `State` field in `Create([Bind("Id,Code,Name,State")]`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and sorry for the long post..

regards
Ashutosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how many times I have said in SO that you shouldn't send your entity model directly from database to the view, and listen to its postback. You should only generate a model (we call it `ViewModel`) that represents what the view needs.

Here is what I will do (I wrote everything by hand, not tested).

#### Create a view model for station creation view:

```
public class CreateStationViewModel
{
    // You shouldn't have Station ID here as it's creation

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public int SelectedStateId { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<int, string> AvailableStates { get; set; }
}
```

#### Initialize this view model on the `get` method:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new CreateStationViewModel
    {
        // Construct a list of available states.
        // We will use it as the dropdown options.
        AvailableStates = _context.States
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => $"{ x.Name }({ x.Code })")
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

#### Build the form on the view:

```
@model CreateStationViewModel
@{
    // You can define a variable here for the dictionary-to-selectListItem
    // conversion.
    // Or you can write an extension method on IDictionary for that purpose.
    var availableStatesSelectListItems = Model.AvailableStates
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.Value.ToString(),
            Value = x.Key.ToString()
        });
}

<form asp-area="" asp-controller="station" asp-action="create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Code" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Code" />
        <span class="form-text" asp-validation-for="Code"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Name" />
        <span class="form-text" asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="SelectedStateId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select class="form-control" asp-for="SelectedStateId"
            asp-items="availableStatesSelectListItems">
            <option value="">- select -</option>
        </select>
        <span class="form-text" asp-validation-for="SelectedStateId"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### Listen to the view model on postback:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(CreateStationViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // You build the entity model from the view model
        _context.Stations.Add(new Station
        {
            Code = model.Code,
            Name = model.Name,
            StateId = model.SelectedStateId
        });
        _context.SaveChanges();

       return RedirectToAction("index");
    }

    // Rebuild the available states, or 
    // better, you can use ajax for the whole form (different topic)
    model.AvailableStates = _context.States
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => $"{ x.Name }({ x.Code })");

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't pass a `State` object to be used as the value of the `<option>` elements inside your `<select>`. Instead, you have to use a simpler datatype. In practice you need to use `StateId` as the value.

Add the property `StateId` to your `Station` class:

```
public class Station
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual State State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
}
```

Also, your SelectList constructor is wrong. The fourth argument ("State" in your example) is supposed to define the default selected item. You don't need to define it here, so leave it out:

```
<select asp-for="StateId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.StatesList, "Id", "Name"))" ></select>
```

Now your `<select>` element should be able to select the correct Id and populate your `StateId` field. Note that in the `[HttpPost]` method, the `State`will still be null, but your database should be updated with the correct `StateId`.

Comment: Your suggestion is working properly. i just felt using both `int StateId` and `State State` a bit redundant.